# Static declaration follows non static declaration?

Tags: c

I know its basic but I am not familiar with C and I couldn't understand the answers here in the subject .

Inside a `C` file I have this functions :

```
void uart_event_handle(app_uart_evt_t * p_event)
{
}
    static void uart_init(void)
    {
    }

    void initialize()
    {
       uart_init();
    }
```

The static function `uart_init()` was inside some example program `main.c` , i am trying to put it inside another C file ( this one)

The error occurs only when I call : `uart_init();` . Otherwise it will not happen.

Comment: Are you trying **to call it** from another `.c` file? In that case you must get rid of static and `extern` your function using a header file.

Comment: No, all of these code is inside a single C file. The error happen on compilation before I even used this file from another place.

Comment: If you put `uart_init` into file `a.c` and you're calling it from `b.c`, then you need to remove the `static`

Comment: Thats not what I am doing Michael .  uart_init is being called from a function inside the same class - initialize()

Comment: Is the order of the functions as you've got above? it looks like somewhere in that file you've got another declaration of `uart_init` that isn't static.

Comment: I guess you are trying to call it in a function implemented before `uart_init `definition.

Comment: Not clear what you're doing, can you create a [MCVE] and post it here?

Comment: Thanks all. Well before that function there is some other not related function that is not static, please see the edit. But there is no other definition in this file of that function. Can it be because its inside another file that I still not yet deleted ?

Comment: @Curnelious What do you mean by "inside some other file"? C files, other than headers, are not supposed to be "inside" anything else.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Well, there are few C files in the program. In one of them there is the same static function init_uart . thats it. but here in this .c file, I am calling the static function from inside the same file. ALL the code here is inside the same place and same c file.

Comment: Your comment "I am trying to put it inside another C file" suggests that there is a declaration of `uart_init()` without the `static` storage class (probably in a header) that is providing the non-static declaration which your definition of the function with `static` is trying to override — unsuccessfully.  We don't have enough code visible to prove that, of course.

Comment: Could you paste the whole error into the question? Just tested getting this error and it says where the other declaration was.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that might be it. I am checking your idea right now. thank you.

Comment: @Curnelious please provide a [MCVE]. Obviously, nobody here is able to reproduce or (even understand ) your problem. And BTW LPs wasn't treating you with disrespect at all, he was probably just a bit exasperated and so am I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a function `static` makes it invisible outside the translation unit. This is similar to declaring fields private in a class, because `static` "hides" the function from all other files.

This lets you define a new function with the same name in some other file without worrying about name collisions. At the same time, `static` makes it impossible to call the function from outside the .c file where it is defined.

Your example provides a use case for making static functions: `initialize` becomes part of the "public" interface of the library, while `uart_init` remains hidden.

Comment: Thats a great explanation, but still I am calling the static function from INSIDE the same C file... what am I missing here ?

Comment: @Curnelious This shouldn't be a problem, [here is a running example](http://ideone.com/3c6tvq). There must be something wrong with the way in which you are compiling your files, because the code in isolation compiles fine.

Comment: Ok I will check it more deeply and accept this. thank you .

Comment: For some reason it compiles, and only when I put this : uart_init(); it says i have multiple declaration.. that means he see this as a declaration ?? but its a call..

Comment: @Curnelious That's really odd - you may want to check if all the braces are balanced in the source code, and you do not have missing semicolons.

Comment: Well, it happens with all static functions in this c file. So every static function I am trying to call, he will say I have multiple declaration. If I do not try to call it, it compiles just fine, that means there is no other declaration, he just see the call as a declaration .

Comment: @Curnelious This could also mean that there is a declaration in the header file which the compiler chooses to ignore because you are not making a call. You may want to try compiling with all warnings enabled, and treating all warnings as errors.